# Simple jQuery tabs not working inside a while loop wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, while-loop, tabs

I just have here a code for a simple working jquery tabs, when I add this inside a while loop only the first loop is working then after that none are working

```
<ul class="tabs-nav">
    <li class=""><a class="active" href="#tab-1" rel="nofollow">Features</a></li>
    <li class="tab-active"><a href="#tab-2" rel="nofollow">Details</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tabs-stage">
    <div id="tab-1" style="display: none;">
<?php 
    if ( !empty($pros_extract) ) {
        echo '<ul class="c_buttels red-check-mark">';
        foreach ( $pros_extract as $pros ) {
            $yy = trim( $pros );
            if ($yy) :
            echo '<li>'. trim( $pros ) .'</li>';
            endif;
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;">
<?php 
    if ( !empty($cons_extract) ) {
        echo '<ul class="c_buttels x-mark">';
        foreach ( $cons_extract as $cons ) {
            $xx = trim( $cons );
            if ($xx) :
            echo '<li>'. $xx .'</li>';
            endif;
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
jQuery('.tabs-nav a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('tab-active');
    jQuery('.tabs-stage div').hide();
    jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).show();
});
jQuery('.tabs-nav a:first').trigger('click');
```

How can I make this work so that each loop is independent to each other, thanks.

You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/1h946zw7/

Comment: Can you define what is $cons_extract?? Your code seems to be working fine when I just used static text.

Comment: Can you show the exact HTML code you have.

Comment: @ShoebMirza its working only on the first loop, its working fine when your on the first loop, so I think the error is on the jQuery code

Comment: may be you have not posted the complete code.

Comment: @ShoebMirza see this example https://jsfiddle.net/1h946zw7/

Comment: let me work around..

Comment: I am trying to work on it also, see my update https://jsfiddle.net/kfr3pgo4/1/

Comment: Hey, you need to use unique id for every tab. see this edited code https://jsfiddle.net/ezo8fjvL/

Comment: Hi @Hemu999 but its dynamic using the while loop, can it be to not use ID

Comment: See I posted my answer with while loop

Comment: Hi @Hemu999 I already answered my own question using this source http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/R85tE/339/ and its much easier, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
jQuery('.tabs-nav').each( function() {
   jQuery(this).children('a:first).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just what I need which is not using unique ID

```
<div class="tabmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <div>
            <p>This is a very simple jQuery tabbed navigation.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>This can contain anything.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Like photos:</p><br />
            <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#0f0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Or videos:</p><br />
            <div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:#f00;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <div>
            <p>This is a very simple jQuery tabbed navigation.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>This can contain anything.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Like photos:</p><br />
            <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#0f0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Or videos:</p><br />
            <div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:#f00;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.tabmenu div').each(function(){
    $(this).children('div:first').show();
});

$('.tabmenu ul li').click(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    var $nav = $(this).parent();
    var $tabCtl = $nav.parent();
    $nav.find('a').removeClass("active");
    $self.find('a').addClass("active");
    $tabCtl.children('div').children('div').hide();

    var indexer = $self.index(); //gets the current index of (this) which is #nav li

    $tabCtl.children('div').children('div:eq(' + indexer + ')').fadeIn(); //uses whatever index the link has to open the corresponding box 
});
```

SOURCE: http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/R85tE/339/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the unique id in the loop. See below the code

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while(put your condition here) {
?>
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li class=""><a class="active" href="#tab-<?php echo $i;?>" rel="nofollow">Features</a></li>
        <li class="tab-active"><a href="#tab-<?php echo $i+1;?>" rel="nofollow">Details</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabs-stage">
        <div id="tab-<?php echo $i;?>" style="display: none;">
    <?php 
        if ( !empty($pros_extract) ) {
            echo '<ul class="c_buttels red-check-mark">';
            foreach ( $pros_extract as $pros ) {
                $yy = trim( $pros );
                if ($yy) :
                echo '<li>'. trim( $pros ) .'</li>';
                endif;
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    ?>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-<?php echo $i+1;?>" style="display: none;">
    <?php 
        if ( !empty($cons_extract) ) {
            echo '<ul class="c_buttels x-mark">';
            foreach ( $cons_extract as $cons ) {
                $xx = trim( $cons );
                if ($xx) :
                echo '<li>'. $xx .'</li>';
                endif;
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
  $i=$i+2;
}
?>
```